# Tuist default scheme for command-line builds

Tags: swift, fastlane, xcodebuild, tuist

I am trying to migrate project on to `tuist` and one place where I stuck at the moment is with `Use {scheme} for command-line builds` I haven't found where/how to set this value and how `tuist`  select the default one.

[image]

The problem I am facing is that I specify scheme for a build with `fastlane` and each scheme has its own provisioning profile. It looks like due to this default command line scheme selected by `tuist`(?) wrong provisioning profile is getting used and the build is failing. If I change manually in Xcode project to use the same scheme for the command line builds as in `fastlane` parameters the builds are successful.

Comment: I don't think you can alter this property using Plist or scheme configurations. However, the actual workaround is calling the correct scheme/configuration during your CLI call, i.e.: `xcodebuild archive -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme SomeScheme -configuration NotLive`

Comment: Thank you, @Bram! The issue wasn't related to the build itself, but rather with the `tuist` manifest. Your response helped guide me in the right direction to address the issue.